# Fiddler Script replacing entire response body

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

I am using  the `static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {` therefor I have `oSession` avaible und now I want to replace the entire string [here](http://pasteboard.co/547pJ9fp3.png).

What property should I use ?

Comment: If you want to modify the response, you need to do this in `OnBeforeResponse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oSession.utilSetResponseBody("whateveryouwant");`